# Which method can grant Read access

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I am having trouble to use C# program directly grant `read` permissions to the `users` using `Client Object Model`, so my current approach is to create a `role` that can have `read` access, then I am going to add my `users` to this `role` I created.

The code I have so far:

```
BasePermissions perm = new BasePermissions(); 
perm.Set(PermissionKind.);  //line 2
```

Now at line 2, when I type `PermissoinKind.`, there are many suggested methods, I am not sure which one can grant the `read` access?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set .ViewListItems, .ViewPages and .Open

That's the least privileges you can have using the UI.

Comment: this is not what i was asking

Comment: Those permissions give read access to ListItems, Pages, Folders and Libraries. That's why I said that is the least privileges you can select (Except Limited Access, but it's another discution)